# CRM Download a file .txt using a button

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I create a button called "Download" with a webresource that contains a function in javascript. So, when the user click on the button, i want to show the txt file. But my code doesn't work. That's my js code:

```
function Download() {
debugger;
var fileContent = "C:\Users\adminrede\Documents\projeto\AlvosCampanha.txt";
    window.open(fileContent);
};
```

I saw this code in the internet.
Hope that someone help. Thank's.

Comment: In what way does your code not work? What is the value of `txtContent`?

Comment: @Fillburt the `encodeUri` is undefined. So `txtContent` don't have any value.

Comment: @Claudia you probably got it the other way around, as Filburt said, encodeUri is undefined because "txtContext" parameter is undefined.

Comment: @dynamicallyCRM you´re right, i already change the code. Thank´s.

Answer (score 0):

By doing so the browser will look for the file on client machine not on the server hosting the script.

Browsers cannot access local files, obviously for security reasons. Host the file elsewhere and then you can do window.open to the location of the file.

Comment: I already do the exercice. I use filesaver.js , and it works. Thanks's everyone.